# Difference between dynamic allocation and ordinary pointers in cpp

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization, declaration, new-operator

I have a problem in following expressions:

```
MyClass *myObject;

MyClass *myObject = new MyClass();
```

What are the differences between them?

Comment: `Why is a raven like a writing desk?`(C) Alice in Wonderland.

Comment: A pointer is a pointer is a pointer. It doesn't care how the memory it is pointed at was allocated. For instance: `MyClass myStackObject; MyClass *myObject = &myStackObject;` is also valid

Comment: One is initialized and one is uninitialized.

Comment: The meaning of the first depends on context.    If it is at file scope, `myObject` is a zero-initialised pointer (i.e. a null pointer, which points at no object, so dereferencing it gives undefined behaviour).   If it is in a function block OR a declaration of a class or struct member, `myObject` is an uninitialised pointer (its value is indeterminate, and simply accessing its value gives undefined behaviour).   The second line initialises `myObject` so it points at a dynamically allocated object.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that one declaration of a pointer of the type `MyClass *` has no explicit initializer and other has an explicit initializer.

In this declaration

```
MyClass *myObject;
```

the pointer is uninitialized and has an indeterminate value if it is declared in a block scope without the storage class specifier `static`.

If it is declared in a namespace or with the storage class specifier `static` it is initialized as a null pointer. That is in this case the declaration is equivalent to

```
MyClass *myObject = nullptr;
```

In this declaration

```
MyClass *myObject = new MyClass();
```

the pointer is initialized by the address of a dynamically allocated object.

You may also rewrite the last declaration like

```
auto myObject = new MyClass();
```

because the type of the name `myObject` will be deduced from its initializer that is from the expression `new MyClass()`.

Pay attention to that you may split this declaration

```
MyClass *myObject = new MyClass();
```

into two statements like

```
MyClass *myObject;
myObject = new MyClass();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Imagine we have a method in class named testFunction(),
in both delaration we can write:
myObject->testFunction();
That's why I am a bit confused. I mean with/without initializing we can use that object.

Comment: @Ali It is undefined behavior when a member function is called using a pointer with an indeterminate value.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that:

- in `MyClass *myObject;`, `myObject` is uninitialized and thus doesn't point at anything meaningful
- in `MyClass *myObject = new MyClass();`, `myObject` is initialized to point at the object that `new` creates.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a;
```

Does it have any meaningful value? Nothing because 'a' is not initialized.

```
int a = 5;
```

Does it have any meaningful value? Yes. 'a' has been initialized to value of 5.

In the same way

```
MyClass *myObject;
```

Does it have any meaningful value? No. myObject is not initialized. So it has some junk / random value.

```
MyClass *myObject = new MyClass();
```

Does it have any meaningful value? Yes. Sufficient memory to hold 'Myclass' has been allocated dynamically and myObject is pointing to starting of the allocated memory.

Comment: Remember that there is no need for `new` most of the time. `MyClass myObject;` will provide a `MyClass` instance with no need for pointers or dynamic allocation.